# VueJs component name reserved words?

Tags: vue.js

When creating a component with the name 'Title' the terminal return an error

`<Title msg="my title"/>`

Is VueJs reserves words so it could explain this ?

Comment: Could you please provide us the returned error ? Also note that, according to the Vue.js Style Guide, your component's name should always have at least two words : https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-word-component-names-essential

Comment: The returned error is : The "Title" component has been registered but not used (vue/no-unused-components), if I give the name "Titles" every thing goes well so with one word...

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because you cannot name a component with an existing html tag. `Title` is a reserved keyword in html. Rename you component to something else.

Comment: I had the same issue using the name 'details' which is also a HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redefine standard HTML tags as your custom component. https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_title.asp

Answer (score 0):

In fact every language has its words reserved, if I were you I would be afraid to put certain words, because they can be conflicting, it follows a list of words that are reserved within the web itself, and it does not make sense to want to create something with a reserved word, a reserved word, would be something that the language itself uses in its composition, and thus could be a conflict if it were used.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element